# MySQL select if set has matches

Tags: mysql, select, set

I have a table with news item, a news item can have keywords, these are stored in a column, keywords.

Now I want to select other newsitems that have matching keywords.

Newsitem 1: food,money,random
Newsitem 2: economy,data,food
Newsitem 3: economy

Newsitem 1 should find newsitem 2.
Newsitem 2 should find newsitem 1 & 3.
Newsitem 3 should find newsitem 2.

Is this posible with MySQL?

Comment: MySQL has a function called `FIND_IN_SET`, which partially covers your problem.  It can take a _single_ string and determine whether it would appear in the keywords column, but matching a set against another set is another story.

Comment: Normalize your data!!!

Comment: Yes, it is difficult if you store the keywords this way in a single field as comma separated values. There is no function in MySQL to split such field values up. If you stored each keyword and its associated newsitem in separate records, then it would be a lot easier task.

Comment: Thanks. Stored it differently. The cms was made before I worked here and they wouldn't change a lot, but i managed to change their minds :D!